# python package initializing a db to nowhere

Tags: python, setup.py, python-packaging

I'm using these instructions for package creation:

https://python-packaging.readthedocs.io/en/latest/command-line-scripts.html

I have a setup like so in the package:

```
mypackage/bin
mypackage/bin/initialize_sqlite.sh
mypackage/mypackage/__init__.py
mypackage/mypackage/a_bunch_of_python.py
mypackage/mypackage/tests/__init__.py
mypackage/mypackage/tests/test_setup.py
mypackage/mypackage/maketables.sql
mypackage/setup.py
```

Where `initialize_sqlite.sh` is

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

sqlite3 my.db < ../mypackage/maketables.sql # creates a Users table
```

and setup.py is

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(name='mypackage,
      packages=['mypackage'],
      scripts=['bin/initialize_sqlite.sh'],
      install_requires=[
          'pysqlite3'
      ],
      test_suite='nose.collector',
      tests_require=['nose'],      
      zip_safe=False)
```

And utils.py is

```
from pathlib import Path
import mypackage

def get_project_root():
    """Returns project root folder.
    """
    return Path(mypackage.__file__).parent.absolute()

ROOT = get_project_root()
DBFILE = str(ROOT.joinpath('my.db'))
```

And my mypackage/mypackage/tests/test_setup.py is:

```
from unittest import TestCase

import mypackage
from mypackage import utils
from pysqlite3 import dbapi2 as sqlite3 

class TestSqlAccess(TestCase):
    def test_sql_access(self):
        conn = sqlite3.connect(utils.DBFILE)
        db = conn.cursor()
        s = db.execute("PRAGMA database_list").fetchall()
        self.assertNotEqual(s, [])
        s2 = db.execute("SELECT 1 from Users LIMIT 1").fetchall()
```

When I am in my package directory and run:

```
./bin/initialize_sqlite.sh
```

It nicely creates

```
mypackage/my.db
```

as I expect it to.

However, when I run the installation:

```
pip install ./mypackage
```

While I see:

```
ll /home/user/anaconda3/envs/myenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mypackage/my.db
```

It is empty and size 0.

In fact, my tests fail:

```
ERROR: test_sql_access (mypackage.tests.test_setup.TestSqlAccess)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/.../tests/test_setup.py", line 14, in test_sql_access
    s2 = db.execute("SELECT 1 from Users LIMIT 1").fetchall()
pysqlite3.dbapi2.OperationalError: no such table: Users
```

What's wrong with my installation bin or paths?  Is it failing to find maketables.sql and not silently not telling me (so it sqlite3 my.db < NULL FILE effectively)?

Is it running the tests /before/ running the bin?

Comment: Addedum---how can I make the bin/initialize_sqlite.sh print its echo statements to stdout on installation?  If I can do that, I can debug what directory it thinks it's in.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check file mode and owner?

```
ls -la
```